# Enzyme elem.simulate('click') n times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I'm learning React and I created a simple counter and I want to do a test that needs to click elements `(+/-)` multiple times. I can do it manually by doing:

```
it('should return correct value if click multiples times', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Counter />);
  const counter = wrapper.find('span');
  const add = wrapper.find('button').at(0);
  const subtract = wrapper.find('button').at(1);

  add.simulate('click');
  subtract.simulate('click');
  subtract.simulate('click');
  add.simulate('click');
  add.simulate('click');
  subtract.simulate('click');
  subtract.simulate('click');

  expect(counter.text()).to.equal('-1');
});
```

Is there any `Enzyme's way to programmatically do simulate method to click n times`?

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe Enzyme provides a way to simulate a click n times. However, you could write your own helper function.

Something like this:

```
function simulateNTimes(enzymeNode, methodName, numberOfTimes) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++) {
    enzymeNode.simulate(methodName);
  }
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
const add = wrapper.find('button').at(0);
simulateNTimes(add, "click", 2);
```

Comment: use lodash... it`s always best to use the helpers from lodash... they are tested and you already have this dependency in your code.... so just call it.. in javascript universe lodash is like a System library at least i consider it like that

Comment: Yeah, `lodash` would be good too. 

I'm not sure if `lodash` was already a dependency on their code. Is it included with `enzyme`?

Answer (score -2):

no there is no such thing because you have lodash implementation.

```
_.times(x, add.simulate('click'));
```

> ```
>    add.simulate('click');
>   _.times(2,() => (subtract.simulate('click')));
>   _.times(2,() => (add.simulate('click')));
>   _.times(2,() => (subtract.simulate('click')));
> ```

Comment: I think you need to wrap it to function in order for your code to work eg:
`_.times(2, () => { subtract.simulate('click'); });`